# Container View inside Tab Bar Controller memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uicontainerview

In my application I have `UITabBarController` inside which I placed `UIContainerView` in order to display set of different pages inside it.

By default, Screen 1 is loading inside that container from the start using storyboards.
Here's a code of how I add `UIViewControllers` to container view and remove, when new one is added:

```
@objc func switchContainerViewContent() {

    switch viewControllerId {
    case "1":

        guard let childVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MedicalInsurancePolicyScreen") as? MedicalInsuranceScreenViewController else {
            return
        }

        self.add(childVC, frame: self.containerView.frame)
    case "2":

        guard let childVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HouseInsurancePolicyScreen") as? HouseInsuranceScreenViewController else {
            return
        }

        self.add(childVC, frame: self.containerView.frame)
    case "3":

        guard let childVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CarInsurancePolicyScreen") as? CarInsuranceScreenViewController else {
            return
        }

        self.add(childVC, frame: self.containerView.frame)
    default:
        break
    }
}

@objc func removePreviousChildViewContent() {

    switch viewControllerId {
    case "1":

        guard let childVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MedicalInsurancePolicyScreen") as? MedicalInsuranceScreenViewController else {
            return
        }

        childVC.remove()
    case "2":

        guard let childVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HouseInsurancePolicyScreen") as? HouseInsuranceScreenViewController else {
            return
        }

        childVC.remove()
    case "3":

        guard let childVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CarInsurancePolicyScreen") as? CarInsuranceScreenViewController else {
            return
        }

        childVC.remove()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Here's add and remove func itself:

```
func add(_ child: UIViewController, frame: CGRect? = nil) {

    addChildViewController(child)
    if let frame = frame {
        child.view.frame = frame
    }
    view.addSubview(child.view)
    child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

func remove() {

    willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    view.removeFromSuperview()
    removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

And this is collection view that handles switching of content inside container:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedPolicyIndex = indexPath

    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedPolicyIndex) as? PoliciesCell else { return }

    cell.selectionView.isHidden = false
    cell.policyNumber.isHidden = true
    cell.policyName.isHidden = true

    collectionView.reloadData()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "removePreviousPolicy"), object: nil)

    switch indexPath.item {
    case 0:
        viewControllerId = "1"
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "switchPolicies"), object: nil)
    case 1:
        viewControllerId = "2"
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "switchPolicies"), object: nil)
    case 2:
        viewControllerId = "3"
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "switchPolicies"), object: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Bug appears when switching from one tab to another in TabBar. For some reason, my container remembers all screens that were presented inside that container and loads them one after other when I open that tab again

**To be more specific, this is what happens:**

- User enters tab with container and switches between different screens,
  opens screen 1, 3, 2, and 1.
- After that, he goes to other tab, and after he returns to that tab for some reason container view starts loading 1, 3, 2 and 1 screens he had opened before.

All this causes increase in memory usage, when this actions are performed for 10-15 times.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't removing the original controllers. You're instantiating new ones and removing them from nothing. removePreviousChildViewContent() does not do what you think it does. If you actually need to add and remove these subviews this way for some reason, you would need to scope the controllers so that the same instance is accessible in both methods.

Comment: You can't create a new instance and expect it to affect another different instance. If you want to remove these controllers this way, make an ivar.

Comment: @Dare Thanks for your help. Can you please show this in code? I'm a bit confused with all this container view logic, thanks...

Comment: Honestly this isn't container view logic, this is just a matter of the fact that instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: _) will always make a new View Controller. It will never give you the same instance as the one you created  in switchContainerViewContent(). You aren't removing anything from anything just making new Controllers and leaving the old ones added to their parents. This is why they won't deallocate.

Comment: @Dare so I should just call `dismiss(animated true, completion: nil)` and that will do the trick?

Comment: @Dare In fact, dismiss didn't help, but a bit advanced deallocation, but your comments helped me to find right path. If you can, please post and answer to this question and i'll mark it as accepted one.